# Moving To New Domain

Tags: dns, seo

I was using a free domain (http://www.co.cc) for my website . And now i bought new **.com** domain. I can't set 301 Permanent Redirect because my old domain is a subdomain. Now my old domain is up, too.

Are there any meta tag for SEO? Should i add any tags or codes to my old webpage's index for indicate search engine bots to my new website ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://www.newurl.com/blah">
```

Add that to the head of each page, referencing the new Domain with the same page name and you'll effectively have a pseudo 301 redirect. The '0' in the meta tag content is the part that sends the user (and bots) from the old URL to the new one instantly. Google has confirmed that it treats meta refreshes with a 0 in the timespace as the same as a 301 redirect.

Try to ensure that a canonical link element also reinforces the new URL.

Alternatively you could add a PHP or ASP header to each page (if your free domain allows server side code).

Comment: or use .htaccess for redirecting old pages to new ones, if that is supported on the server

Comment: i'm using php header for recently . Still i need canonical meta tag ?

Comment: the PHP headers would exist on the old pages (on the old host). The canonical link element would exist in the <head></head> of the new pages to reinforce that they are the *canonical* versions

Answer (score 0):

I've moved the website from dumalana.com to [www.alampur.com](http://www.alampur.com).

I might be missing some value, but whenever you do this find/replace process again, you can notice the values and tables that should be updated and add them to this script.

If CMS you use is Wordpress, Best to do in cpanel with SGL command about options, posts, post content and post meta:

UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://olddomain.com','http://newdomain.com');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com');

Also see Searching Data using phpMyAdmin and MySQL | Packt Publishing. And Search RegEx is a good WP plugin to be able to search and replace with Grep through all posts and pages.

It's work. No matter if you install wp in sub-domain